# Running Total example

Tags: sqlite

I have the following Data:

```
id  customer  date                value1  value2  isTrue
10  13  2013-08-20 00:00:00.0000  170     180680  0
11  13  2013-09-02 00:00:00.0000  190     181830  0
12  13  2013-09-07 00:00:00.0000  150     183000  1
13  13  2013-09-14 00:00:00.0000  150     183930  0
14  13  2013-09-16 00:00:00.0000  150     184830  0
15  13  2013-09-19 00:00:00.0000  150     185765  1
16  13  2013-09-30 00:00:00.0000  800     187080  0
17  13  2013-10-02 00:00:00.0000  100     188210  0
28  13  2013-10-04 00:00:00.0000  380     188250  1
```

How can i have the following Results,where SumValue1 is the summury of value1 until field isTrue gets True and resets after and Difference Value2 is the difference of field value2 everytime the IsTrue field gets True?

```
id  customer  date                value1  value2  isTrue  SumValue1  DifferenceValue2
10  13  2013-08-20 00:00:00.0000  170     180680  0
11  13  2013-09-02 00:00:00.0000  190     181830  0
12  13  2013-09-07 00:00:00.0000  150     183000  1       510        2320
13  13  2013-09-14 00:00:00.0000  150     183930  0
14  13  2013-09-16 00:00:00.0000  150     184830  0
15  13  2013-09-19 00:00:00.0000  150     185765  1       450        2765
16  13  2013-09-30 00:00:00.0000  800     187080  0
17  13  2013-10-02 00:00:00.0000  100     188210  0
28  13  2013-10-04 00:00:00.0000  380     188250  1       1280       2485
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Juergen d

Comment: In your example, the first `DifferenceValue2` value is not calculated according to the description.

Comment: Are the records sorted by `id` or by `date`?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlRollupAndCube

Comment: In your example, the first DifferenceValue2 value is not calculated according to the description. – CL.
Yes but I take the difference because it is the first record. So you are right i had to check it as true...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` ordering,  this query will do:

```
SELECT
    id, customer, date, value1, value2, isTrue,
    CASE isTrue WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT TOTAL(value1) FROM t WHERE customer=t2.customer AND id>t2.prev_id AND id<=t2.id) END AS SumValue1,
    CASE isTrue WHEN 1 THEN value2-(SELECT value2 FROM t WHERE customer=t2.customer AND id=t2.prev_id) END AS DifferenceValue2
FROM (SELECT *, CASE isTrue WHEN 1 THEN COALESCE((SELECT id FROM t AS _ WHERE customer=t.customer AND date<t.date AND isTrue ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1), -1) END AS prev_id FROM t) AS t2;
```

Steps by step:

Previous `id` where `isTrue` is given by:

```
SELECT id FROM t AS _ WHERE customer=t.customer AND date<t.date AND isTrue ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Using `COALESCE(..., -1)` will ensure a non-null `id` before all others (`-1`).

`SELECT *, CASE isTrue WHEN 1 THEN ... END AS prev_id FROM t` will return all rows from `t` with column `prev_id` added.

At last, querying `SELECT TOTAL(value1) FROM t WHERE customer=t2.customer AND id>t2.prev_id AND id<=t2.id` and `value2-(SELECT value2 FROM t WHERE customer=t2.customer AND id=t2.prev_id` over previous results will return desired results.